# Using soql query how to get all events from startdatetime to enddatetime in apex

Tags: apex, soql

Hi i want to get the all the events in between startdatetime to enddatetime.but  i am not getting the records.

My code is:

```
@RemoteAction
    public static string eventdata(Datetime starts,Datetime ends){
 for(Event evnt: [select Id, Subject, isAllDayEvent, StartDateTime, EndDateTime from Event where  ownerid=:userinfo.getUserId() and startdatetime>=:starts and enddatetime<=:ends]){
}
}
```

in the vfpage:function getEventData() 
        {

```
        // records are retrieved from soql database
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.WisconsinCalendarController.eventdata}', 
            // controller and method names
            start.toUTCString(),
            end.toUTCString(),
            function(result, event)
            {
                console.log(result);
                if (event.status) 
                {
```

In the select query i am not getting values.

The values of starts is 2016-04-22 00:00:00 ends is 2016-04-30 00:00:00
I tried in the query editor if the starts and  ends value format  like 2016-04-22T00:00:00Z then i am getting the values but in the coding i give starts and ends values like above format  i am getting Invalid date/time: 2016-04-21T20:00:00Z

Comment: Any luck resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass `String` variables for `Datetime` parameters. Change your method to accept `String` parameters instead. In order to be able to use `Datetime.valueOf`, you will need to use a format like `2016-04-22 00:00:00` instead. You will then need to perform the conversion to `Datetime` yourself:

```
public static void myMethod(String startTime, String endTime)
{
    Datetime startDt = Datetime.valueOfGmt(startTime);
    Datetime.endDt = Datetime.valueOfGmt(endTime);
    // other logic
}
```